# W3 Total Cache and fragment cache - not able get it to work

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have followed steps from [there](https://1fix.io/blog/2015/02/22/page-fragment-caching-w3-total-cache/) but I'm not able to get fragment cache to work (which was main reason to get PRO version)

Example code inside a template looks like:

`<!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
echo 'The time is '.date( 'H:i:s', time() );
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->`

so in that case I expect to see *The time is* and right time but it works only once and then it shows *echo 'The time is '.date( 'H:i:s', time() );* as a plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to define `W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY` constant in your wp-config.php file

```
define('W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', 'FRAGMENT_CACHING');
```

then you can test it with the code below (any template):

```
<?php echo date("H:i:s"); ?>
<br>

<!-- mfunc FRAGMENT_CACHING -->
echo date("H:i:s");
<!-- /mfunc FRAGMENT_CACHING -->
<br>


<div id="mydiv"><p>The current time is 
<!-- mfunc FRAGMENT_CACHING echo date("H:i:s"); -->
echo date("H:i:s"); 
<!-- /mfunc FRAGMENT_CACHING -->
</div>
```

Comment: Fragment caching is now a Pro feature, so don't be surprised if it doesn't work. You will want to look for the Fragment Caching plugin and see if its status is enabled. If it's "disabled," fragment caching won't work.

Comment: Page fragment cache is not a pro feature, Fragment cache is. There's a difference. Page fragment cache is what is described here and will work in the free version too.

Comment: Also you have to use Page Cache mode `Disk: Basic`. It won't work with `Disk: Enhanced`. You can find this setting in General Settings.